# if radio button is selected, enable label1.text

Tags: asp.net, forms, radio-button, label

I want to enable label1 if I click/select radiobutton1 in ASP.NET

if i click the radio button then label1 should be enable (without clicking the submit button)

Comment: I don't believe HTML labels have an "enabled" state.  What do you actually want to happen when the radio button is selected?  Simply change the label's color?  Toggle it from  invisible to visible?  Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "RadioButton.CheckedChanged " events to do this and then on this event write `Label1.visible=true`  and  you need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` for radio buttoni.e.

i.e. `<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: you need to set `AutoPostBack="true" ` for radio button i.e.  `<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"`

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed to set AutoPostBack.

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" 
            oncheckedchanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />
```